# How to make a div fill the height until the next absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css

How to make a div fill the whole height between top of parent to top of next absolutely bottom-positioned element ?

See codepen here: http://codepen.io/LouisDoe/pen/vGLJVB

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="maxHeight">
    blabla
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <div>row 1</div>
     <div>row 2</div>
     <div>row 3</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 .content { position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; }
```

I'd like to make

```
 <div class="maxHeight">
 </div>
```

the full available height.

Thanks

Comment: Javascript solution is easy.

Comment: Why are you using `position:absolute;`?

Comment: No can do. You have to use js for that as explained in my answer

Comment: @NenadVracar because I need it at the bottom (it's an app)

Comment: @RonenCypis See my answer below. Problem solved without JS. Just set heights of elements.

Comment: Do you need browser support for IE9 or less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). If you set `min-height: 100vh` on `.wrapper` it will take full height of window. And with `flex: 1` on `.maxHeight`, that element will take rest of remaining height and push `.content` div to bottom of window.

```css
* {
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.maxHeight {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.content div { 
  padding:10px; 
  border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="maxHeight">blabla</div>
  <div class="content">
     <div>row 1</div>
     <div>row 2</div>
     <div>row 3</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great that seems to do the job ! Can you help me vertically center the text "blabla" in the flexbox ?

Comment: Yes you can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/153/, if you don't want horizontal center remove `justify-content: center`

Answer (score 0):

Problem :-(

The whole purpose of `position:absolute;` is to "pull" an element out of the page's flow, so there is no "available height" since the absolutely positioned element doesn't take any place of its parent element.

You can achieve this using **javascript** by programmatically calculate the height of the parent element, and subtract the bottom positioned element's height from it...

**EDIT:**

Considering your HTML, you can set both `.maxHeight` and `.content` elements to be `position:absolute;`, with different `bottom` & `height` values like so:

```
.content {
  bottom:0;
  height:150px;
}
.maxHeight {
  top:0;
  bottom:150px;
}
```

It's not dynamic, but will achieve what you want.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to avoid position absolute then ?

Comment: @Louis Is there a reason why my answer below isn't doing what you want?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, the first div's height must not include the bottom div.

Comment: @Louis I'm not sure i understand exactly what do you want to achieve... can you better explain?

Comment: @Louis maxHeight does not include the height of content in my answer. It gets 100% of whatever is available after content is accounted for. If it was including the height of content, the page would need to scroll as there would be more height than the viewport could display. Did you look at the codepen?

Comment: @Louis just updated my answer... maybe it will help you :-)

Comment: @RonenCypis I can't control .maxHeight 's height, because it's a dynamical list.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ...when inspecting .maxHeight, it goes below content.

Comment: @Louis you only need to know the `.content` element's height. not the `.maxHeight`

Comment: @RonenCypis sorry I meant that I can't control .content's height (dynamical list)

Comment: @Louis So as i said before, use js to dynamically detect it's height, and then proceed as described :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do a sticky footer....

something like this: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check this js solution: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ghys86u/1)

css:

```
.wrapper {position: relative; height: 100%;}
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  wrapperHeight = $(".wrapper").height();
  contentHeight = $(".content").height();
  $(".maxHeight").height(wrapperHeight-contentHeight);
});
```